# Display a dropbox dynamically- Javascript/Jquery in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display 3 different drop down boxes triggered with 4 different buttons. Drop down boxes should be displayed in #apple div. 
when Button B1 is clicked- drop down contains - Apple, mango, papaya
when button B2 is clicked- drop down contains - B2A, B2B
when button B3 is clicked- drop down contains - B3A, B3B, B3C, B3D
when button vanish is clicked drop down disappears.  Here is what I have done->

```
var para = document.createElement("SELECT");

    var t1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var apple = document.createTextNode("apple");

    var t2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var orange = document.createTextNode("orange");

    var t3 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var peach = document.createTextNode("peach");

     t1.appendChild(apple);
     t2.appendChild(orange);
     t3.appendChild(peach);

    para.appendChild(t1);
    para.appendChild(t2);
    para.appendChild(t3);
    document.body.appendChild(para);
```

Problems I am facing->
1) The dropdown box is displayed outside area #apple.
2) Some text appears in #apple div  "[object HTMLSelectElement]"
3) Is there a better way to this ?
4) How should I implement vanish button?
Here is the full code. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzryb4yf/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: b2,b3 and vanish don't have implementation?

Comment: No. B1, b2 and B3 all display 3 different dropdown boxes. (Although only one of them should be visible at a time).

Comment: Where do you want the drop-down to appear when selecting B1, and where do you want "[object HTMLSelectElement]" to appear? Inside the box?

Comment: @esc drop down should appear inside #apple division..  "[object HTMLSelectElement]" is a text erroneously appearing when I click button B1. I do not wish it to appear anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will solve your problem concerning the positioning inside the div box, just include jquery library inside your jsfiddle otherwise it won't work

```
   $("#apple").prepend(para);
```

Here is your full function code. Make a call then,

```
  function myFunction() {
    var para = document.createElement("SELECT");

    var t1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var apple = document.createTextNode("apple");

    var t2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var orange = document.createTextNode("orange");

    var t3 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var peach = document.createTextNode("peach");

     t1.appendChild(apple);
     t2.appendChild(orange);
     t3.appendChild(peach);

    para.appendChild(t1);
    para.appendChild(t2);
    para.appendChild(t3);
    $('#apple').empty();
    $("#apple").prepend(para);

}
```

Function call:

```
 function run(x){
        if(x===1){
         var answer = myFunction();

        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I overwrite the current HTML. This function (prepend()) appends to the current HTML. I wish to display only one drop down at a time.

Comment: Do you mean by that How would you use the other buttons?

Comment: Yes that would answer my question. Here is your version (http://jsfiddle.net/rzryb4yf/2/). When we click B1, the #apple area becomes "dropdown + here" which was "here" earlier. I want to delete (overwrite) "here" to display only the dropdown. Something that innerHTML() would do.

Comment: Well, just put the   $('#apple').empty(); before the prepend() function I ll edit the post

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resolve

## 1 is to use `appendChild` to append the new element inside your apple div.

`function run(x){
        if(x===1){
         var answer = myFunction();
        document.getElementById("apple").appendChild(answer);
        }
    }`

## 2 `[object HTMLSelectElement]`

This appeared because you were trying to assign a Html Object to
inner-html property which expect actual Html text code.

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: appendChild() will append to my existing HTML. What if I want to overwrite the HTML? (I wish to display only one drop down at a time).